# permissions denied when saving image on sdcard

Tags: android, file, permissions, sd-card

This function is used to save image on sdcard (I have tested it on the emulator only):

```
public String SaveImage(String URL,String imagename){

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File dir = new File(path + "/bh");
        if(!dir.exists())
             new File(path + "/bh").mkdir();
        Log.i("in save()", "after file");
        File mImageFile = new File(path+"/bh/"+imagename);

        if(mImageFile.exists())
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try{
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mImageFile);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            in.close();
            return imagename+".jpg";
        }catch(IOException ex){
            Log.e("==== Error in saving image ====",ex.getMessage());
            return "";
        }
    }
```

I have added the required permissions like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mobile.bh"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.0.3" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="mobile.bh.activities.BHActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="mobile.bh.activities.RecipesListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="mobile.bh.activities.RecipeInfoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="mobile.bh.activities.IngredientsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="mobile.bh.activities.MethodActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="mobile.bh.activities.SpicesListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.SpicesCategoriesActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.CategoryActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat output ?

Comment: where did you put those permission? In which tag of the Manifest?

Comment: here is the full Manifest file

Answer (score 0):

You also need to use the Internet permission since you're connecting to the internet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your emulator support SDCard ?

Have a look at this great answer, it might be the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/11468278/1635817